# How to enable the automatic asterisk in Visual Studio 2010 when adding a multi-line comment in C++?

Tags: c++, ide, styles, comments

I've seen many people complain about Visual Studio automatically adding an asterisk in multi-line comments for C#. **My question is**: How do I *enable* this behaviour for C++?

Example:

```
/**
 * I want
 * my comments
 * to look like this
 */

/**
But,
they look like this
*/
```

Thanks!

Comment: The vim plugin for visual studio does that.

Comment: For whatever reasons, Microsoft has chosen not to introduce intelligent commenting features into C++ that have existed on the C# side since 2002 or 2003.  I can understand C++ lacking some of the code formatting and intellisense options, since C++ parsing is much more complicated than C# parsing, but one would think that comment formatting would have been quite doable.  Anyway, you'll need to install one of the extensions or plugins mentioned here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed in Visual Studio 2019 that if you place your text cursor just after the first asterisk in a block comment and hit enter it will automatically put an asterisk on the next line.

> Step 1) Place text cursor to the right of the first asterisk in a
> block comment separated by a newline.

[image: step 1]

> Step 2) Hit enter and Visual Studio 2019 will automatically place a
> asterisk on the next line.

[image: step 2]

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is automatically enabled in new Visual Studio installs, but you can set whether it is enabled or disabled by going to "Tools" -> "Options", then under "Text Editor" -> "C/C++" -> "Code Style"[ -> "General"], then twiddle "Insert existing comment style at the start of new lines when writing comments" to your liking:
[image: options panel]
Obligatory image of the options panel, since no one reads text anymore.

(I myself have the feature disabled, since I find it annoying—when I comment out code, adding random asterisks when I make small changes is clearly deleterious.)